# VS 2019 Package in build options change output directory

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I have set up my project to to generate NuGet Package on build. It puts it into the **/bin/release** folder but I would like to put it in the solution folder.
Does anyone know if that is possible?

[image]

I have tried using the Post build events, but it appears that the package is created after the build process...

```
xcopy $(ProjectDir)bin\release\*.nupkg $(SolutionDir) /y
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve the issue, I have two solutions for you.

============================================================

**Solution 1**

**1)** the target to generate nuget package is `GenerateNuspec`, so you should write a target after it.

[image]

**Add** these in your `xxx.csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="CopyToSolutionFolder" AfterTargets="GenerateNuspec">


        <ItemGroup>
            <File Include="$(ProjectDir)bin\release\*.nupkg"></File>
            
        </ItemGroup>

        <Copy SourceFiles="@(File)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)"></Copy>
    </Target>
```

===========================================================

**Solution 2**

**2)** you can also change the output folder of the nuget package under the packing process from the root cause.

Use this in your `xxx.csproj` file

```
<PropertyGroup>
      <PackageOutputPath>$(SolutionDir)</PackageOutputPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**And** it will let `GenerateNuspec` target output the nuget package to the solution folder.

Comment: Much better than my solution, which was to change the post build events to "Path"

Comment: Solution 1 did not work for me, Solution 2 worked for me. Instead of $(SolutionDir) I put in C:\temp to test, perhaps that affected the solutions